# Sharing apache's error_log with other users (non-root)

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, file-sharing, logging

I've got other users on my linux system - how can I 'share' the system's error_log so its readable by other users on the system?

Answer (score 4):

If there is no harm in making the apache error log readable by **all others** on your system you

1. `chmod o+r /var/log/apache2/error.log`
2. Edit `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` and look for or add a line that says `create 640 root adm`  and change that also to something appropriate like `create 644 root adm`.

It would be less secure to put everyone in the group of the apache daemon (say `www-data`). A better option would be to use ACL's (see `man setfacl`) and allow very specific access to the file.

(Paths are on a Ubuntu/Debian system).

Comment: I dont seem to have an 'apache2' root@vps [/etc/logrotate.d]# ls -al
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 11 19:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 61 root root  4096 Mar 12 12:52 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   167 Aug 30  2010 httpd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   223 Mar  4  2004 lircd
-rw-r-----  1 root named  163 Jan 20  2010 named
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    61 Sep  8  2010 rpm
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   232 Sep 15  2010 samba
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   154 May 25  2010 snmpd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   306 Apr  3  2010 syslog
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   100 Apr  4  2010 yum

Comment: root@vps [/etc/logrotate.d]# find / -name 'apache2'
root@vps [/etc/logrotate.d]#

Comment: Just try to find out if your apache logfiles are log-rotated. If no special file exists, maybe there's a line in `/etc/logrotate.conf`. This is just to make sure a daily logrotation does not re-set your changed file permissions. If there's no rotation, simply ignore this hint. Btw - what linux are you using?

Comment: centos/redhat i think